# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and XSLT 2.0 support

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

As per following URL I enabled the XSLT 2.0 support how ever the looks like the TryIt service is not working when I do that.

[Achala Blog Entry](http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-get-xslt-20-support-with-wso2.html)

I get following error when I try to use TryIt service.

```
[2012-09-10 11:47:03,491]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin' logged in at [2012-09-10 11:47:03,0491] from IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0
Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 32 of :
  Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
Warning: on line 286 of :
  The attribute axis starting at a namespace() node will never select anything
Error on line 1603 of :
  XPTY0004: Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item
  type xs:string
[2012-09-10 11:47:09,515] ERROR - Util Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string
; SystemID: ; Line#: 1603; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string
```

Is there any workaround so that we can use XSLT 2.0 and TryIt both with WSO2 ESB 4.0.3.

Hoping for answer.
thanks
Abhijit

Comment: Can you provide your .xsl file too? Because my answer below (from Achala Blog) works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the standard XSLT processor by a newer one being able to process XSLT 2.0 like documented in the Blog [solution for WSO2 ESB 4.0.3](http://achala11.blogspot.ch/2012/04/how-to-get-xslt-20-support-with-wso2.html):

1. Remove xalan-2.7.0.wso2v1.jar in ESB_HOME/lib/endorsed/
2. Remove saxon-8.9.0.wso2v1.jar from ESB_HOME/repository/components/plugins
3. Copy the saxon9he.jar to lib/endorsed and start the server.

[SAXON 9 you can download here](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

Be aware that you'll get the SOAP envelope and body also as Input to your XSLT, so maybe you need to have the xsl:template for these elements too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope|soapenv:Body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

...
```

Comment: I am aware that new ESB supports XSLT 2.0. When I change as per the above blog "Try It" Service does not work. This is not my xsl.

Answer (score 0):

The latest WSO2 ESB (v4.5.0) supports XSLT 2.0 [1], via Saxson.

[1] http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/announce/2012-September/000026.html

Regards,
/Nuwan

Comment: I am aware of it. It is not possible to change the ESB on the fly when environment is there already in place.